# Julia: Assigning figure-letters to each subplot with PyPlot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, julia, subplot, imshow

I am using the `PyPlot` package to generate figures in Julia. Each figure contains several different plots that I am organizing using `subplot`. I want to assign a figure letter in the top left corner of each subplot so that the first subplot gets a bold 'a)' in the top left corner, the second subplot gets a bold 'b)' in the top left corner, and so on. Currently my best attempt is based on using `title`:

```
using PyPlot

figure(1);
subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4,wspace=0.4)
subplot(221) ; imshow(rand(20,20)) ; title("a)",loc="left",fontweight="bold") ; xlabel("x") ; ylabel("y")
subplot(222) ; imshow(rand(20,20)) ; title("b)",loc="left",fontweight="bold") ; xlabel("x") ; ylabel("y")
subplot(223) ; imshow(rand(20,20)) ; title("c)",loc="left",fontweight="bold") ; xlabel("x") ; ylabel("y")
subplot(224) ; imshow(rand(20,20)) ; title("d)",loc="left",fontweight="bold") ; xlabel("x") ; ylabel("y")
```

This seems to work okay. But ideally the figure letters should be placed slightly higher above the figure and farther to the left (such that the figure letter is on the left side of the y-axis label). Is there a way to accomplish what I am aiming for?

Comment: does `figtext` work in Julia's pyplot?

Comment: Just "text"  should work.

Comment: `annotate` would be better than `text`, you have more control over the placement.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (written in python)

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import count
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2, 2)


def label_subplots(ax_lst, *, upper_case=True,
                   offset_points=(-5, -5)):
    start_ord = 65 if upper_case else 97
    for ax, lab in zip(np.ravel(ax_lst), (chr(j) for j in count(start_ord))):
        ax.annotate(lab, (1, 1),
                    xytext=offset_points,
                    xycoords='axes fraction',
                    textcoords='offset points',
                    ha='right', va='top')


label_subplots(ax_lst, upper_case=True)
```

[image: example output]